# Storing array of values in one variable

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

This is My Code. I'm preparing a offline quiz system. This code shows multiple questions with there option field. Now in radio variable, currently it stores the option of question submitted by user who's name is q1. Since the name of every question set is dynamic,how can I store multiple values in radio variable ?

Like option of q1, q2... and so on ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentPath = ((location+"").replace(/%20/g, " ").replace("file:///", "").replace("/", "\\").replace("index.html", ""));
    var pad = currentPath+"\\quiz.mdb";
    //var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pad;
    var strConn = "Provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;Data Source=" + pad;
    var cn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    cn.Open(strConn);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    var SQL = "SELECT * FROM ques_bank WHERE quizno = 'q_001'";
    rs.Open(SQL, cn);
    var sList = "<form target='sendinfo' id='infoform' onSubmit='return handleClick()'>";
    while (!rs.EOF) {
        sList = sList + 
        "<p>"+rs("question")+ "</p><br>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='q"+ rs("ID") +"' value='a' />"+rs("optionA")+"<br>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='q"+ rs("ID") +"' value='b' />"+rs("optionB")+"<br>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='q"+ rs("ID") +"' value='c' />"+rs("optionC")+"<br>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='q"+ rs("ID") +"' value='d' />"+rs("optionD")+"<br>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='q"+ rs("ID") +"' value='e' />"+rs("optionE")+"<br>"+
        "<input type='text' id='rank_list' name='q_id' value='"+ rs("ID") +"' /><br>"+
        "<hr>";
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    document.write(sList+"<input type='submit' value='Submit'/></form>");

    function test() {
    }

    //submit function
    function handleClick() {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName("q1");
        var found = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {       
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                alert(radios[i].value);
                found = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found == 1) {
            alert("Please Select Radio");
        }    
        //event.preventDefault(); // disable normal form submit behavior
        return false; // prevent further bubbling of event
    }

    rs.Close();
    cn.Close();
</script>
```

Comment: You could create new attributes to store whatever you want. For instance         `<input type="radio" value="1" userID="whatever" chocolateBar="bingo" name="myRadios[]" id="rb2"/>`

Comment: but how could i store the values in one variable ?